# regex variable from script 32/34 characters

Tags: c#, regex, xpath, character, var

from the following code I am trying to get the data from the script variable. I'm interested in the text between ""

var code = "a37965dcd8421328a767c697448ed735";

```
            XPathResult xpathResult = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.EvaluateXPath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/script");
        var foundNodes = xpathResult.GetNodes();
        foreach (var node in foundNodes)
        {
            var x = node.TextContent; // get text text contained by this node (including children)
            GeckoHtmlElement element = node as GeckoHtmlElement; //cast to access.. inner/outerHtml
            string inner = element.InnerHtml;
            string outer = element.OuterHtml;
            String pattent = ".[0-9a-zA-Z]{34}$.";
            Match match = Regex.Match(inner, pattent);
```

regex is correct? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help us to help you if you could provide a [mcve]. Try to isolate what the problem is. There could be problems with the Document, XPath, node, casting or the regex. Give use something that isn't doing what you want and tell us what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Regex string can try to use `[0-9a-zA-Z]{32,34}` instead of `.[0-9a-zA-Z]{34}$.`

The `.` could be removed.

[regex online](https://regex101.com/r/SCdyog/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex rule can try like this:

```
bool result = Regex.Match(inner, @"^[0-9a-zA-Z]{32,34}$").Success;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If result equal `true`, it match success!